# Javascript setTimeout fires as many times in as page loaded by ajax

Tags: javascript, ajax, settimeout

I am executing setTimeout function in a page which loads via ajax call. but if i click the link to load the page again, i afraid the last setTimeout call still continues and the number of intervals of the calls set by setTimeout executes multiple times.

tried this is the remote page:

```
var RefreshInterval = null;
clearTimeout(RefreshInterval);

function someFunction()
{
....
    setNextRefresh();

}

function setNextRefresh() {
    console.log(wifiRadarRefreshInterval);
    RefreshInterval = null;
    clearTimeout(RefreshInterval);
    RefreshInterval = setTimeout('someFunction();', 20*1000);
}
```

Comment: Could you fiddle it?

Comment: what's the point of doing `RefreshInterval = null; clearTimeout(RefreshInterval);` ? if `RefreshInterval` is null you can't clear the previous timeout

Comment: i found once this trick for some browsers don't work with clearTimeout()

Answer (score 1, accepted):

declare `var RefreshInterval = null;` outside of page loaded by ajax and use this code on the page:

```
clearTimeout(RefreshInterval);

function someFunction()
{
....
    setNextRefresh();

}

function setNextRefresh() {
    console.log(wifiRadarRefreshInterval);
    clearTimeout(RefreshInterval);
    RefreshInterval = setTimeout('someFunction();', 20*1000);
}
```

Comment: @AmitShah setTimeout will return id (a number) that can be used with clearTimeout, if you set to null the clearTimeout don't know what to clear.

Answer (score 0):

Do not use this

```
var RefreshInterval = null;
clearTimeout(RefreshInterval);
```

You are actually `assigning a null and then trying to clear it`. Which will not work, **The timeout must be cleared by using the `clearTimeout` and by passing the variable which was assigned to the setTimeout**. Here you will end up passing a null so the timer is never cleared.

Here is a small sample which will demonstrate a fix to your problem **[JS Fiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/vy36zh7u/1/)**

So insted of setting the variable to null and then trying to clear it, Just check if the variable is not defined and if it is defined clear it, else move on.  Use the code  below, Also you must remove the top two lines as mentioned

```
   function setNextRefresh() {

     console.log(wifiRadarRefreshInterval);

     if (typeof RefreshInterval !== 'undefined') {
       clearTimeout(RefreshInterval);
     }

     RefreshInterval = setTimeout('someFunction();', 20*1000);
   }
```

Click on the button say like 4 times, The output should be printed only once. That is if the ajax call is made 4 times the set time out must execute only once. Check below snippet for demo

```js
 var clickCount= 0; // just to maintain the ajax calls count

function NewPageSimilator(clicksTillNow) { // this acts as a new page. Let load this entire thing on ajaX call

  if (typeof RefreshInterval !== 'undefined') {
    clearTimeout(RefreshInterval);
  }

  function setNextRefresh() {
    window.RefreshInterval = setTimeout(printTime, 3000); //20*1000
  }

  function printTime() {// dumy function to print time  
    document.getElementById("output").innerHTML += "I was created at click number " + clicksTillNow + '<br/>';
  }
  setNextRefresh();
}

document.getElementById("ajaxCall").addEventListener("click", function() { // this will act as a ajax call by loading the scripts again
  clickCount++;
  NewPageSimilator(clickCount);
});

document.getElementById("clear").addEventListener("click", function() { //reset demo
  clickCount = 0;
  document.getElementById("output").innerHTML = "";
});
```

```html
<p id="output">

</p>
<button id="ajaxCall">
  AJAX CALL
</button>
<button id="clear">
Clear
</button>
```

Comment: Thanks @Reddy, but i am using "use strict". so must be first declare the variable.

Answer (score 0):

if i don't want to declare it in parent page, here is the solution i found:

```
//Clear previously loaded calls if exists
try{    clearTimeout(wifiRadarRefreshInterval); }catch(e){}
var wifiRadarRefreshInterval = null;

function somefunction(){
    ....
    setNextRefresh();
}

function setNextRefresh() {

    try{

        clearTimeout(wifiRadarRefreshInterval);
        wifiRadarRefreshInterval = null;
        wifiRadarRefreshInterval = setTimeout('somefunction();', 20*1000);
    }
    catch(e){
        console.log(e.message + e.stack);
    }   
}
```